# Get HTML Table content with VBA for Excel using arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, web-scraping, html-table

Trying to get data from the **second table** of this website as the first table only contains the elements of a drop list, for whatever reason this is included as a table in the HTML!

The code refers to a similar page in which, however, the first table is not present, there it works fine, just not on the page with two tables that have different contents.

So the idea is to use the code below, but first to **skip** the first table and extract only the contents of the second table (tr/td) that match the elements in the given array.

Does anyone have any idea how the code would have to be modified to handle this? Thanks!

Snippet with both tables (run the snippet to see the droplist):

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <select size="1" onchange="nextpage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'-1','-1')">
    <option value="1-1-11">1-2</option>
    <option value="all" selected="selected">all</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
<table border="0">   
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>valign=“top“ aling“left“>
    <nobr>Description</nobr></td>
```

Code section including a function

```
Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, R As Long, c As Long, headers(), row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
Dim results() As Variant, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

headers = Array("HDR01", " HDR02", " HDR03", " HDR04")

ReDim results(1 To 100, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    Set table = html.querySelector("table")
    Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim lastRow As Boolean
  
 For Each row In table.Rows

       Dim header As String
       lastRow = False

        html2.body.innerHTML = row.innerHTML
        header = Trim$(row.Children(0).innerText)        

        If header = "Description" Then          
            R = R + 1
            Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set dict = GetBlankDictionary(headers)
        End If

        If dict.Exists(header) Then 
           dict(header) = Trim$(row.Children(1).innerText)       
        End If        

        ....

        If lastRow Then
            populateArrayFromDict dict, results, R
        End If

 Next
 
 With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
 End With
```

The function:

```
Public Function GetBlankDictionary(ByRef headers() As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        dict(headers(i)) = vbNullString
    Next

    Set GetBlankDictionary = dict
End Function
```

I need something like this that works:

```
  If table.Border = "1" Then   'with Droplist
    Set table = html.querySelectorAll("body").Item(1)   'skip table0
    ElseIf table.Border = "0" Then  'wihtout Droplist
    Set table = html.querySelectorAll("body").Item(0)   'start with this table
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the correct attribute and value to the selector to get the right table

```
Set table = html.querySelector("table[border='0']")
```

Comment: I did loop through tables just to see what was there and 3 tables were present, only the desired one had border = 0. So this code works great! Now there is issue of multi-page return and how to move to other pages to continue retrieving records. That may require looping through tables anyway to at least get page count from the page navigator which sits in first table. Unless there is an abbreviated way to reference that as well. Sounds like Jasco will have another question posted soon.

Comment: @Qharr: Typical again...with a single codeline you let the devil evaporate with his trident. Wish you all A's  :-)

Comment: @June7: Three Tables??? Qharr's Code works for multipages, I'll check whether it works in Access too...actually it should!

Comment: @Jasco, I tested with "Celle" and it pulls only 10 of 11 records. 11th record is on second page. Yes, 3 tables with "Celle", 2 of them are the page navigation dropdowns. I added quite a few comments to our chat.

Comment: @June7: No...no more traps and pitfalls....add **&all=1** to the end of the url and it will work because in this case all objects will be listed on page 1, no more scrolling necessary :-)

Comment: Add to which URL, the first one? Did that and the m2 data is not retrieved. Did get 11 records though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231398/discussion-between-june7-and-jasco).